# How to use session with id?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have an order and I want to after save, get in session current `id` of order for next page `reports`.

```
use Session;

public function store(Request $request)
{
            $order = new Order($request->all());
            $order->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $order->title = $request->title;
            $order->body = $request->body;
            $order->id = $request->session()->get('id');
            $order->description = $request->description;
            $order->save();
            session(['order_id' => $order_id]);
            return redirect()->route('reports.index')->with('order_id', $request->id);
}
```

In notes page has a `input hidden` for get `session of article id`.

```
     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="{{ Session::get('order_id') }}" name="id" id="id">
```

But I see `input hidden`. It is blank . "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused here

```
session(['order_id' => $order_id]);
return redirect()->route('reports.index')->with('order_id', $request->id);
```

when you're returning something with "->with()" it stores in session so why use session() ? and **$order_id is not defined** in your method.
and best way to put something in session is like this

```
Session::put('order_id');
```

I think if you do this

```
->with('order_id', $order->id); // You will get the current order id created
```